# Console.WriteLine not working in Debug mode

Tags: vb.net, console, ide, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

I have a WinForms application (not a console app) and until today I was able to see the outputs from `Console.WriteLine()` in Output window of the Visual Studio IDE. Now I only see these:

```
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'R:\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120_clr0400.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\dfd75630ade67ae60abbed1c6429af70\mscorlib.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\tv_x64.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_34ae2abd958aedeb\comctl32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'R:\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\11cafc25fa98032abe341dd1ec1cba00\System.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\205e1980e1a8e9d676d162cd47ee9e45\System.Core.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.V9921e851#\637346c2a2fce6899011d0ebb6a62492\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\71e7cd0ba79f168cfedc1088660dedd4\System.Drawing.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\a30fc8e132a5d01979c0ad05802161a2\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runt73a1fc9d#\d9f6cda51be90d1082e03f24d016b87f\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Configuration\da2025ddb2e4cda0d5565cd20b13e09b\System.Configuration.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\8f3a43bbaf05195e35bd48211260b2f5\System.Xml.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_932b3b5547500489\GdiPlus.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
The thread 0x308c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.18006_none_623f33d3ecbe86e8\comctl32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Management\582311e3d1bc8df9d9705b3bb649956b\System.Management.ni.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Management.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WMINet_Utils.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutils.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wbemcomn.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemprox.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\fastprox.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
The thread 0x12cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

If I run in the Release mode I can see the outputs but of course I can't debug.

Note: If I start a new project the `Console.WriteLine()` works just fine. So there must be something wrong with the Project Properties, I guess, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Look at `Enable the VS Hosting Process` in Debug

Comment: Whether it's checked or not, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to:

> Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols-> Specify excluded modules

You may for some reason have them listed to be excluded.

(`disabled by Include/Exclude setting`)

Comment: Nope, I did it on purpose to hide all "'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded" traces but as you can see they didn't disappear.